# Как передать список значений типа String в один запрос SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Как мне передать в SQL запрос список слов и вернуть все найденные совпадения по всем переданным словам также списком?

Я пишу так:

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT title FROM books WHERE awards LIKE (" + "'%" + ", ".join(selected_awards) + "%'" + ")"
)
result = cursor.fetchall()
conn.close()
print("SQL search result: " + str(result))
```

Однако мне возвращаются значения только под одному 1-му слову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, ваш код содержит SQL-инъекцию: просто так складывать пользовательскую строку и SQL-запрос категорически нельзя.

Во-вторых, это решается банальным соединением нескольких `LIKE` через банальный `OR` или `AND` (я не понял из текста вопроса, что вам конкретно нужно, испольуйте что вам нужно):

```
sql = "SELECT title FROM books WHERE "
where = []
args = []

# Собираем все условия LIKE, которые потом соединим через OR/AND
for award in selected_awards:
    where.append('awards LIKE ?')
    # Слова передаём отдельно, чтобы защититься от SQL-инъекции
    args.append('%' + award + '%')

# Собираем SQL-запрос до конца
sql += ' OR '.join(where)  # или AND

# И запускаем. sqlite автоматически заменит вопросики на нужные слова
cursor.execute(sql, args)

result = cursor.fetchall()
conn.close()
print("SQL search result: " + str(result))
```

В-третьих, возможно, вы пытаетесь имитировать полнотекстовый поиск; по-хорошему для него следует использовать специальные движки типа Sphinx, ElasticSearch или Whoosh.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)